# Error "Incompatible operand types Module.Category and ULocale.Category"

Tags: java

so I am trying to `Get Modules list by Category`

Here's the code that I'm trying to do

```java
public List<Module> getModulesByCategory(Category c){
        List<Module> modules = new ArrayList<Module>();
        
        for(Module m : this.modules) {
            if(m.category == c)
                modules.add(m);
        }
        return modules;
    }
```

I get a error on the line `if(m.category == c)` saying `Incompatible operand types Module.Category and ULocale.Category`

App: `Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2020-03`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Add the imports so we can see it. You probably have the wrong package imported

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the object of the same type. Based on the error it looks like you are trying to compare the object of a different type(Object of Module.Category to object of ULocale.Category).
Make sure you are passing the same type of Category object while passing an argument to getModulesByCategory() and inside the same method.